# Where does greenlock-express saves lets-encrypt certificates?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, lets-encrypt

I'm using [greenlock-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock-express) to generate lets-encrypt certificates. However, I don't know where the certificate is stored. Therefore, everytime I started my application, it generated a new certificate, because I use docker, and so I reached the lets-encrypt maximum number of certificates.

Where does greenlock saves the certificates? I want to mount this folder as a volume so docker reuses it on every startup. But is mounting this folder enough?

Answer (score 1):

I have just ran into the same problem.

You can set up the path to the certificates using this command:

```
npx greenlock defaults --store greenlock-store-fs --store-base-path <path_to_certificates>
```

All that's left is to mount your volume.

I'm also pointing my `configDir: '<path_to_certificates>'` there as the config does not seem like something you want to commit. If I ran out of certificates, I'll let you know.